# Delphi 7 to XE8 assigning binary ADO parameter values

Tags: delphi

I'm converting a report that resides in a DLL to XE8 so that I can update our report control, which is problematic in Windows 10. In doing this, I've had to replace our ADO data access controls with the built-in ADO controls.

The issues is that our data uses binary keys, and I've run into an issue assigning values to query parameters. In our code, the keys are passed around as strings, and assigned to the parameters and converted by the control at runtime.

Previously, utilizing the old control, it utilized the Delphi DB unit which contains a method `.AsBlob` which was used in the assignment. See below...

```
Qry.Close;
Qry.ParamByName('@Id').AsBlob := IdStringValue;
Qry.Open;
```

In the control's implementation it handled setting the property, which called into `SetAsBlob`. See below...

```
Type TBlobData = string;
```

...

```
procedure TQryParameter.SetAsBlob(const Value: TBlobData);
begin
  Self.DataType := ftVarBytes;
  Self.Value := StringToVarArray(Value);
end;
```

Part of the issue is that Data.DB has changed `TBlobData = string;` to `TBlobData = TArray<Byte>;`.

I've tried assigning these values to the query parameters following the same method used in the previous implementation, but it doesn't work.

```
Qry.Close;
Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('@Id').DataType := ftVarBytes;
Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('@Id').Value := ADODB.StringToVarArray(IdStringValue);
Qry.Open;
```

I get a fairly generic MSSQL error due to the parameter mismatch, "Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation."

The ADO query parameter is defined as `VarBytes` and the stored procedure accepts `BINARY(6)` for its only parameter so everything appears to be correct.

I've tried casting `IdStringValue` from `String` to `AnsiString` prior to calling `StringToVarArray` but it makes no difference.

Anyone know of a way to deal with this? Thank you.

Comment: Since `AsBlob` wants an array of bytes now, that is what you should give it, eg: 
`Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('@Id').AsBlob := TEncoding.Default.GetBytes(IdStringValue);` Or whatever `TEncoding` you want to use

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't seem to be able to call `Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('@Id').AsBlob` using the builtin ADO control... `.AsBlob` doesn't show up as a value method for `TParameter` but does for `TParam`. I tried setting the parameter directly, `.DataType := ftVarBytes;` and `.Value := TEncoding.Default.GetBytes(IdStringValue);` but get the same error about the parameter type mismatch.

Comment: Use the [`.Value`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TParameter.Value) property instead of `.AsBlob`, and don't set the `.DataType` manually, let the param figure it out for itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I gave your suggestion a shot, with similar results. I also removed and readded the parameter from the design-time control to allow it determine and set the datatype. I put together a test project where I pull a value from another query and use that value to set the parameter of another and it didn't work either.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I converted the string to hex and compared it to the field in the data. The values do match, but the parameter mismatch on the stored procedure is still a problem. Thanks for your help, still trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added the same stored proc to a simple test project and assigned the value to the parameter ... it runs without issue. When run from the DLL it's giving me the error about the mismatch for the parameter. /sigh

Comment: @RemyLebeau I got it working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string value to array of bytes when assigning the parameter.

`Qry.Parameters.ParamByName('@Id').AsBlob := TEncoding.Default.GetBytes(StringValue);`